# Typing M in Android Studio opens Configure Component screen

Tags: android, android-studio

Whenever I press Shift/M on my keyboard the Configure Component screen opens. It means that the only method to type M in any Java or XML file is to type M somewhere else (for instance in Word), and copy/paste it in Android Studio.
How can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Go to:
Preference -> KeyMap

Over there you should locate the shortcut that's linked to SHIFT+M and remove it.

Comment: Thank you orimen, but I didn't see your answer before I posted mine. The menu structure in your version of Android Studio seems to be different from mine.

Comment: yeah, I gave you the MacOS path. On windows it's as you mentioned in your comment: File->Settings->Keymap

Answer (score 0):

It seams as if I solved my problem, although I do'nt know exactly what I did.
I was looking for keyboard shortcuts in Android Studio, and I found them in File->Settings->Keymap->Visual Studio.
I found lots of keyboard shortcuts there, but I didn't find Shift+m nor Configure Components, so I didn't change anything.

But after I went back to my files I could type M by pressing Shift/M!